# How to prove the index of $SO(n)$ in $O(n)$ is 2?

Tags: group-theory

How to prove the index of $SO(n)$ in $O(n)$ is 2 where $O(n)$ is the orthogonal group of degree $n$ and $SO(n)$ is a special orthogonal group of degree n.

Comment: $SO(n)$ is the kernel of the determinant map: $O(n)\to \{\pm1\}$

Comment: Yes but the reason this is true is because orthogonal matrices must have determinant $\pm 1$. (So in fact the index is $1$ over fields of characteristic $2$.)

Answer (score 1):

The determinant map can be shown to be a homomorphism: $d:O(n)\to \{\pm1\}$.  By the first isomorphism theorem, $O(n)/\rm{ker}\,d\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

But, as @J.W.Tanner points out, $\rm{ker}\,d=SO(n)$.